# Soyuz MS spacecraft battery voltage?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, electronics

This wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_MS) contains a sentence:

> A fifth 906V battery with 155 Ampere-hour capacity was added to support the increased energy consumption from the improved electronics.

906 V seems very high, 90.6 V is believable.

Is there any other information about Soyuz DC system voltage?

Comment: 906V would have its advantages - you could save some launch weight in high current wiring :)

Comment: @rackandboneman: You would need less weight for the wiring conductors, but more weight for wiring isolation. But the reliability of so many battery cells in series to get 906 V would be too small.

Comment: Very high voltage batteries of small capacity and low max current, built as stacks of thin metal foil and electrolyte soaked paper (voltaic cells), are reliable and lightweight enough, a good source of high voltage where such is needed. But 155Ah is a very respectable capacity and way more than I'd see in form of a voltaic pile.

Comment: Insulation is light, and most any plastic insulation can withstand 1000V if transient free and kept safe from damage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

["Soyuz: A Universal Spacecraft"](https://books.google.com/books?id=dbGchpi1HP8C&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=soyuz%20dc%20system&source=bl&ots=SepTgcZk1G&sig=kBSOBaLcP-Cy4PS3zHxmhLCigdE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj59NOegqTcAhVUCTQIHUIyBTcQ6AEImwEwDg#v=onepage&q=volts&f=false) says the electrical system produces 23-34 volts. I saw a reference to a nominal 28VDC supply to the spacecraft in the Soyuz launcher manual; 28VDC is a global standard for aircraft power supplies.

I think "906V" is a part number, not a voltage; [the source for that section of the WP page](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/soyuz-ms-sep.html) says (my bolding):

> Finally, the spacecraft was upgraded with an extra (fifth) power-storage battery, **known as 906V**, with a capacity of 155 ampere-hour.

Comment: Confirmed by the Soyuz Crew Operations manual, several batteries are listed as 909A, 906B, etc.

Comment: The [Soyuz Crew Operations](https://www.infosondas.com/2017/04/pdf-soyuz-crew-operations-manual-soycomrop-19final/) manual also contains the system voltage of 23 to 34 volts.

Comment: ...and Cyrillic 'B' is latin 'V'.